# obtaining OAuth2.0 token using asp.net mvc core

Tags: google-api, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

[OAuth 2.0 Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) describes getting oauth2.0 token using asp.net mvc application, but in asp.net mvc core application, controller is of type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` while AuthorizationCodeMvcApp method expects System.Mvc.Controller object.

```
var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Is there a different way to obtain OAuth2.0 token in asp.net mvc core? I tried casting core mvc controller, but no luck.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You might want to check this https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/933

Comment: is there any alternative that you would suggest?

Comment: all I can tell you is to wait.  Its on the list we are working on it.   Otherwise you could write your own library.   I have done it to support .Net 3.5